# Как с помощью библиотеки BeatifulSoup получить нужные данные?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Я хочу получить данные населения за 2012 год в Китае со страницы https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q148, используя функцию, в которую в качестве параметров переданы 2012 год и название страны China.

На странице https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q148#P1082 есть отдел population, и за каждый год написано количество населения.

Я хочу узнать именно population за 2012 год. Но не исключено, что потом моя функция захочет получить данные за 2013 или за 2018 годы и т.д. Поэтому должна быть возможность в зависимости от года получать данные population.

Как мне сделать это с помощью библиотеку `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: 1) Скачать 2) Получить . Больше конкретики, пожалуйста. Какие именно данные? Я вот открыл ту страницу и не понял что оттуда нужно вытаскивать :) А так вот пример скачивания и парсинга: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a91253cadca1b9a3b8cbcffc6fdef488c4a7fc0e/https_%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B4_%D1%80%D1%84__crash_statistics/common.py#L30

Comment: @gil9red   я теперь  уточнила вопрос

Comment: Нужно больше разжевывать :) Например, вот нашел я на той странице 
`population`? Там есть даты, такие как `1 July 2012` и какие-то числа, такие как `1,375,198,619`. Вам и нужно это получить? Мол за 2012 год было `1,375,198,619` народу? Это и нужно в вопросе показывать. То, что вы новичок, я думаю и так понятно, поэтому лучше вместо этого указания больше примеров и скриншотов добавили бы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покажу по шагам для Китая. [Весь код тут](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/581735aa63f20a0b4b5e7e0e5faa964a2cdd93d8/html_parsing/get_population_from_wikidata.py).

Алгоритм:

- Скачать. Пусть будет через `requests`
- Распарсить. Будет через `BeautifulSoup`
- Извлечь нужные данные

---

#### Шаг 1

```
# Скачать
import requests
rs = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q148')

# Распарсить
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

# Извлекаем
# P1082 -- идентификатор для population
population_node = root.select_one('#P1082')

# Перебор строк в соседнем от population столбце
for row in population_node.select('.wikibase-statementview'):
    # Небольшая хитрость -- берем только первые 2 значения, по идеи это 
    # будут: количество людей и дата
    number_str, data_str = row.select('.wikibase-snakview-value')[:2]

    # Вытаскиваем текст из
    number_str = number_str.text.strip()
    data_str = data_str.text.strip()

    print(data_str, number_str)
```

В консоли будет:

```
1 July 2012 1,375,198,619
2010 1,332,810,869
1 July 2015 1,397,028,553
1 July 2016 1,403,500,365
1 July 2014 1,390,110,388
1 July 2010 1,359,755,102
1 July 2017 1,409,517,397
1 July 2011 1,367,480,264
1 July 2013 1,382,793,212
```

---

#### Шаг 2

Данные вы получили, теперь нужно обработать:

- Дату привести к одному виду -- только год. `1 July 2012` -> `2012`
- Собрать в контейнер, например в словарь
- Для удобства обернуть скачивание и обработку в функцию

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_populations(url: str) -> dict:
    rs = requests.get(url)
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

    # P1082 -- идентификатор для population
    population_node = root.select_one('#P1082')

    populations = dict()

    # Перебор строк в соседнем от population столбце
    for row in population_node.select('.wikibase-statementview'):
        # Небольшая хитрость -- берем только первые 2 значения, поидеи это будут: количество людей и дата
        number_str, data_str = row.select('.wikibase-snakview-value')[:2]

        # Вытаскиваем текст из
        number_str = number_str.text.strip()
        data_str = data_str.text.strip()

        # Делаем разделение и берем последнуюю часть, после приводим к числу
        # "1 July 2012" -> 2012, "2010" -> 2010
        year = int(data_str.split()[-1])

        # Добавляем в словарь
        populations[year] = number_str

    return populations


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q148'
    populations = get_populations(url)
    print(populations)  # {2012: '1,375,198,619', 2010: '1,359,755,102', 2015: '1,397,028,553', ...

    # Выводим данные с сортировкой по ключу: по возрастанию
    for year in sorted(populations):
        print("{}: {}".format(year, populations[year]))

    # 2010: 1,359,755,102
    # 2011: 1,367,480,264
    # 2012: 1,375,198,619
    # 2013: 1,382,793,212
    # 2014: 1,390,110,388
    # 2015: 1,397,028,553
    # 2016: 1,403,500,365
    # 2017: 1,409,517,397
```

---

#### Шаг 3

Для удобства сделаем функцию, которая вернет данные по указанному году:

```
...

def get_population_by_year(populations: dict, year: int) -> str:
    # Если такой год не будет найден, вернем -1
    return populations.get(year, -1)


# Аналогично get_population_by_year, но сначала вытащит данные из 
# указанного url, а после достанет значение по year
def get_population_from_url_by_year(url: str, year: int) -> str:
    populations = get_populations(url)
    return get_population_by_year(populations, year)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q148'
    populations = get_populations(url)
    print(populations)  # {2012: '1,375,198,619', 2010: '1,359,755,102', 2015: '1,397,028,553', ...

    ...

    print(get_population_by_year(populations, 2012))  # 1,375,198,619
    print(get_population_by_year(populations, 2013))  # 1,382,793,212
    print(get_population_by_year(populations, 2014))  # 1,390,110,388
```

Comment: Это очень классно, спасибо большое)) Надеюсь, когда-нибудь я тоже так научусь)